# What tactics should Baron Blade use in the Power Splicing scenario?

Tags: sentinels-tactics

I just played through the first scenario of Sentinels Tactics, Baron Blade vs Tachyon/Legacy/Ra, where he is trying to blow up the power plants.

Baron Blade got totally destroyed, he only managed to kill 2 of the plants, and that was when we were playing wrong and allowing him to attack the plants from higher ground. Once we fixed that, he was mostly useless. Should he be trying to avoid even being touched with teleport? Should he be trying to incapacitate the heros? It seems like fighting is a losing battle for him.

I [watched the demo game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP3pcnJpjgI) for the scenario in which Baron Blade won, but it seemed that the heroes played really poorly. The heroes were running away from baron blade, never using aim, and doing attacks that lowered movement (which might be good in other scenarios, but in this one, baron blade can teleport to get large distances anyway, so it's probably useless).

Answer (score 3):

I have played as Baron Blade multiple times and never lost Scenario 1.
The key is using the terrain to your advantage.  There are eight potential targets of which you have to take out six.  That means you should be teleporting to an unoccupied target just about every time.
Pay close attention to turn order.  Remember that you get two turns for every turn any particular other hero gets.  Is Ra over by himself protecting a target?  As soon as he takes his turn, jump over there and splice it, then jump away on your next turn before he gets to act again.
Always wear your suit for +1 defense, and don't be afraid to change out your teleport for your restributor (and +1 Defense token) on a turn when you're going to let them hit you - especially if you can burn an action to Dodge.  Never attack unless you know you can get a kill, like a six-space Fusion shot with Aim.
Good luck.  With a good handle on the terrain and the Baron's defensive powers, you should have the Megalopolis power grid in your hands in no time!